# Stop repeating div content in PHP AJAX MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to retrieve the data dynamically from MySQL database into web page using AJAX technique but the div content is repeated. I want to refresh the div without duplicate the information.

here is the code

api.php

```
<?php 

require 'db.php';
$query = "SELECT * FROM variables"; 
$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);           
$data = array();
while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result) )
{
  $data[] = $row;
 }
echo json_encode( $data );
?>
```

client.php

```
  <html>
   <head>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"> 
     </script>
     </head>
      <body>

        <h2> Client example </h2>
        <h3>Output: </h3>

         <div id="output"></div>

         <script id="source" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

         function ajaxcall() 
           {
           $.ajax({                                      
            url: 'api.php', data: "", dataType: 'json', timeout:2000, 
           success: function(rows)        
            {
            for (var i in rows)
                {
               var row = rows[i];          
                var id = row[0];
                   var vname = row[1];
              $('#output').append("<b>id: </b>"+id+"<b> name: </b>"+vname)
              .append("<hr />");
               }

              } 
              });
                }; 
                   ajaxcall();
                   setInterval(ajaxcall, (1 * 1000));

                 </script>
                 </body>
                </html>
```

Comment: You want to fetch new data and append to existing one without fetching data already in the div?

Comment: Just replace the `$('#output').append(...)` with `$('#output').html(...)`.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "refresh the div without duplicate the information"? Do you want to just empty all `div` content each time you populate?

Comment: exactly, I want to fetch the data again without repeating it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just change this

```
 success: function(rows)        
            {
            for (var i in rows)
```

to this

```
success: function(rows)        
            {
            $('#output').html(''); // empty the container div and append new HTML
            for (var i in rows)
```

Answer (score 3):

try to use  `$('output').empty();` before the loop in order to avoid duplicating content.

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can do it as:

```
var htmlData = '';
for (var i in rows)
     {
      var row = rows[i];          
      var id = row[0];
      var vname = row[1];
      htmlData + ="<b>id: </b>"+id+"<b> name: </b>"+vname+"<hr />";
   }
$('#output').html(htmlData);
```

Comment: Thanks, @DanielBrunner for suggestion